# Can 3.3V circuit power be used to power garage door opener that uses 3V CR2032 coin battery?

Tags: power-supply

I have a garage door opener normally powered by 3V CR2032 coin cell.  I want to power it from the 3.3V power rail of a circuit.  Can I use the 3.3V directly?  Will it damage the garage door opener?  Or must I bring it down to 3V with a resistor first?

Comment: It may help if you post some photos of what your garage door opener looks like inside.

Comment: It depends whether the circuit can accept 3.3V as input. Typically yes, but it depends on the actual circuit design.

Answer (score 3):

A CR2032 coin cell may start off with a voltage as high as 3.4V - see [this datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1496885.pdf) from POWER GLORY BATTERY TECH (HK) CO., LTD. (via Farnell.)

[image]

If the garage door opener can withstand a fresh coin cell at up to 3.4V, it should also tolerate a 3.3V supply (provided it really is 3.3V or less.)

If you want more certainty, you could try inspecting the main parts of the garage door opener and determining the ratings of any integrated circuits present.

Answer (score 1):

A resistor is not a good idea.  Why not put a schottky diode in series with the output?